# /MANIFEST default value in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, manifest

We're using scons 2.3.4 and are in the process of upgrading to Visual Studio 2013 (from 2008).

In our scripts we do not set the /MANIFEST link flag. Instead we relied on the default behaviour to generate the manifest file.

This worked fine in VS2008. But on VS2013 the linker is not creating a manifest. This seems incorrect. According to the documentation /MANIFEST is still the default behavior in VS2013.

I've manual enabled the /MANIFEST flag in our scripts which sorts the problem out.

But I'm curious to know why this step is necessary at all?

Comment: No manifest is required to locate the runtime DLLs since VS2010.  All that's necessary is the manifest entry that declares the program compatible with UAC.  Generated automatically with default Linker + Manifest settings.  Have a look-see by creating a dummy project with the IDE.  /MANIFEST and /MANIFESTUAC required.

Comment: This seems to be the answer I'm after. If you'd like to copy and paste the above as an official answer I can mark it correct.

Comment: I don't want to support such an answer.  Feel free to post it yourself please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"No manifest is required to locate the runtime DLLs since VS2010."

Found this to be true. There is no need enable the /MANIFEST flag at all.